# First Java EE Project using REST

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, service

I've been going off of http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-137171.html and downloaded the files but I'm a little lost since I've never done this before.

I've installed Tomcat and Eclipse Java EE IDE but I don't know what kind of project to use to create a webservice and how to load and compile the code to the service.

Am I going about this the right way in using eclipse?

Comment: What's the question?  How to use REST and Java EE?  What kind of sample project to start?  Where to find a sample project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an REST (JAX-RS) example I put together.  You will probably find part 4 the most helpful:

- [Part 1 - The Database](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-15.html)
- [Part 2 - Mapping the Database to JPA Entities](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-25.html)
- [Part 3 - Mapping JPA entities to XML (using JAXB)](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html)
- [Part 4 - The RESTful Service](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html)
- [Part 5 - The Client](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html)

Answer (score 3):

That article is old.  Since then, the Java standards committee created a new API named [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAX-RS) (The REST counterpart to JAX-WS).  Like JAX-WS, this is meant to standardize REST web service layers.

Its reference implementation is [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), which supports JAX-RS 0.8, 1.0, and 1.1.

I understand that [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) has support for JAX-RS 0.8, but it is unclear about 1.0/1.1 support.

JBoss has [RESTEasy](http://jboss.org/resteasy).  However, it is not immediately clear which versions of JAX-RS are supported by RESTEasy.

Another popular JAX-RS framework is [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/).  Unfortunately, I can't open their site from here to say which versions of JAX-RS they support.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're creating is a lightweight RESTful service you can also look at [GlassFish](http://glassfish.java.net/) which provides a simple http server for REST.

Answer (score 0):

You'll create a web project to deploy a web service of any kind.  It'll be packaged in a WAR and deployed on Tomcat.